# Cohomology of a space with local coefficients and singular cohomological dimension

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

If $X$ is a space with (singular) cohomological dimension n, i.e. $H^i(X;\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all $i>n$, (may be cohomology with rational coefficients). 
Is it true that $H^i(X;\mathcal{L})=0$ for all $i>n$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is a system of local coefficients on $X$?
Can someone give some reference?

Comment: First you should write $H^i(X,G)=0$ for any abelian group $G$, I guess, although I don't know a counterexample offhand.
Secondly, the claim is false for arbitrary sheaves, see Example 3.1.6 in Dimca's Book on sheaves in topology. But for locally constant sheaves the question is tricky.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is no.  It's easiest to give examples arising from group cohomology (so the spaces are $K(\pi,1)$'s).  The reason for this is that if $G$ is a nontrivial group, then there must exist some local coefficient system $M$ such that $H^i(G;M) \neq 0$ for some $i$.  Indeed, let $H < G$ be a nontrivial cyclic subgroup, and let $M$ be the coinduction of the trivial $\mathbb{Z}$-module from $H$ to $G$.  Then Shapiro's lemma (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%27s_lemma)) says that

$$H^i(G;M) = H^i(H;\mathbb{Z}),$$

which has to be nonzero for some $i$.

Dramatic examples of groups with the property you seek are so-called "acyclic groups".  These are groups $G$ such that $H^i(G;\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all $i \geq 1$.  For a nice survey of such groups, see the last section of

MR1967745 (2004c:20001) 
Berrick, A. J.(SGP-SING)
A topologist's view of perfect and acyclic groups. Invitations to geometry and topology, 1–28, 
Oxf. Grad. Texts Math., 7, Oxford Univ. Press, Oxford, 2002.

Comment: This is pretty slick!

Answer (score 3):

How about $X=\Bbb RP^2\times L^2_3$, where $L^2_3$ is the cone of the $3$-fold cover $S^1\to S^1$. Here $H^4(X;\Bbb Z)\simeq\Bbb Z/2\otimes\Bbb Z/3=0$, but $H^4(X;\mathcal L)\simeq\Bbb Z\otimes\Bbb Z/3$, where $\mathcal L$ is the pullback of the orientation sheaf of $\Bbb RP^2$.

As a side remark, "singular cohomological dimension" is not something that people normally do, perhaps because singular cohomology is not Brown representable, or because of the Barratt-Milnor example of a compact subset of $\Bbb R^3$ (in fact it is just the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb Z$) which has infinite "singular cohomological dimension". If you do care about spaces not homotopy equivalent to CW-complexes, you can look up some books on traditional dimension theory, which deal with usual (that is, Cech) cohomological dimension. For spaces homotopy equivalent to CW-complexes, there's no distinction because all ordinary cohomology theories coincide.

Comment: Yes. A good thing to bear in mind is that cohomology of a covering space of $X$ (even with constant coefficients) can always be interpreted as cohomology of $X$ itself with locally constant coefficients.